# Firebase Functions: Retrieve user language

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to implement a multi-language api using Firebase functions, and checking for a way to get user language.

From client side I can check/set user language using `firebase.auth().languageCode`.

I am looking how can I retrieve this information server side: Is it possible to get user language from server side (Firebase Functions / Firebase Admin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's language is not automatically passed along to Cloud Functions. If you need this information, you'll have to pass it along from your own code.